# How to exploit open redirect vulnerability?

Tags: web-application, exploit, attacks, url-redirection

I have the following open redirect vulnerability:

```
<?php
$redirectUrl = $_GET['url'];
header("Location: $redirectUrl");
?>
```

This exploit sends user from your page to evil page:

```
example.com/?url=example.com/faq.php
example.com/?url=evil.com/sploitCode.php
```

How do I insert `evil.com/sploitCode.php` into the victim's page/URL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Exactly as you are doing. The idea of open redirect vulnerabilities is to use the trust a user has in a specific website (the vulnerable site), and exploit it to get them to visit your website.

So you would send this link to a user: `example.com/?url=evil.com/sploitCode.php`. Because the website they see is `example.com`, and they trust them, they will click on it (in theory). On the other hand, if you would have send them `evil.com`, they would not click on it, because they do not know or trust it.

You can also obfuscate the url further `example.com/some/nice/sounding/path/%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F/?url=evil.com/something-less-evil.php?some-unneded=parameters`. Then you can also wrap it up in a nice `a` tag, so users will be less suspicious (then the main advantage is that hovering over the link will show them an innocent link at first glance) .

Comment: Can i also hack a user's session, in order to embed this code into the page he views on example.com ?

Comment: @user2598085 Not really. You can highjack a session, or perform session fixation, and I guess theoretically this could enable an open redirect (eg if you change your example code to `$redirectUrl = $_SESSION['url'];`, and set `$_SESSION['url']` in a different script) without the need to send the evil url, just the normal url, but this is a very contrived example, and if you can highjack/fixate a session, open redirect isn't the most interesting attack to perform.

Comment: A redirect to any given domain is a security issue indeed. But what about a user input `path` only? An open redirect but only to any given path *on the same domain*.

Comment: @Bell If the filter is working correctly it's not an issue. Note though that eg filtering `http://` and `https://` is not enough, `//google.com` eg works as well. Note also that if the CSRF protection is a simple referer check and if the application has GET requests that change server state (or if a POST to GET downgrade is possible) this would enable CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the URL that you give as example, can also be written as such:

`example.com/?%75%72%6C=%65%76%69%6C%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%73%70%6C%6F%69%74%43%6F%64%65%2E%70%68%70`

The domain, `evil.com`, is no longer visible in the link. Nor that it's a redirect at all. It doesn't look exactly normal, but how often are there funny-looking links in emails that include some tracking code? The domain is perfectly legit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear. Does the site already have Open Redirect vulnerability (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect)? If it does you proceed as **tim** already have said.
If it doesn't and you are interested in general methods of getting your malicious code into its pages, then either you hack into the site ("getting shell"), or find some kind of Unrestricted File Upload vulnerability (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload), or bruteforce the password for ftp account with enough privileges to replace site's pages and then update the .php page your targets will frequently visit with your malicious code.

Comment: your answer doesn't make sense